# Proving multivariable limit exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that the following limit exists?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^4\sin^4 x}{(x^3 + y^4)^2}$$

After setting $y=mx$ and $y=m\sqrt x$ I found isn't dependant on $m$ and it's $L=0$. But I'm not being able to understand how to prove it with epsilon delta.

Could you help me?

Comment: Hint: Since $x^6+y^8\leq (x^3+y^4)^2$ and $\frac{|\sin x|}{|x|}\leq 1$, $$0\leq \frac{x^4\sin^4 x}{(x^3 + y^4)^2}\leq\frac{x^6}{x^6+y^8}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\sin^2x\leq\sin^2 x
$$

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful.  But  for x<0 , x⁶+y⁸≤(x³+y⁴)² isn't correct. Actually it's inverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually limit doesn't exist.
After setting  y⁴=mx⁴-x³   , using sin⁴x=x⁴ and simplifying.
Limit equal :   1/m²       So it's dependant on magnitude of "m".